# While loop in Qt5 for Database Connection Fails to Display Message Box Warning for wrong credentials

Tags: c++, mysql, qt5

Very new to qt5. I am having trouble getting a login/registration system working.
"Login Successful" dialog displays when entering correct user/pass but it doesn't show the failed attempt "Login Failed" Error Window when entering wrong pass or user, it doesn't do anything.

I've tried to remove the while loop but still can't get it to work.

Original Code:

```
  void MainWindow::on_btnLogin_clicked()
{
    QString username = ui->usernameLogin->text();
    QString password = ui->passwordLogin->text();

    if(db.open()){
        // Creating my Queries
  //  QMessageBox::information(this, "Database Connected", "Database Connection Successfully");

    QSqlQuery query(QSqlDatabase::database("MyConnect"));

    query.prepare(QString("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username AND password = :password"));

    query.bindValue(":username", username);
    query.bindValue(":password", password);

    if(!query.exec()) {
        QMessageBox::information(this, "Failed", "Query Failed to Execute");
    } else {
        while (query.next()) {
            QString usernameFromDB = query.value(1).toString();
            QString passwordFromDB = query.value(2).toString();

            if(usernameFromDB == username && passwordFromDB == password) {
                QMessageBox::information(this, "Success", "Login Success");

                MyDialog dialog;
                dialog.setModal(true);
                dialog.exec();

            } else {
                QMessageBox::information(this, "Failed", "Login Failed");
            }

        }
    }
    } else {
    QMessageBox::information(this, "Database Failed", "Database Connection Failed");
    }
}
```

And now one of the very many versions i've tried.

```
void MainWindow::on_btnLogin_clicked() // Login Button
{
    QString username = ui->usernameLogin->text();
    QString password = ui->passwordLogin->text();

    if(database.open()){
    QSqlQuery query;

    query.prepare(QString("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username AND password = :password"));

    query.bindValue(":username", username);
    query.bindValue(":password", password);

    query.exec();

    if(!query.exec()) {
      QMessageBox::information(this, "Failed", "Query Failed to Execute");
    }

        if (query.next()) {
            QString usernameFromDB = query.value(1).toString();
            QString passwordFromDB = query.value(2).toString();

            if(usernameFromDB == username && passwordFromDB == password) {
                QMessageBox::information(this, "Success", "Login Success");

                MyDialog dialog;
                dialog.setModal(true);
                dialog.exec();

            } else {
                QMessageBox::information(this, "Failed", "Login Failed");
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: The problem is the query returns no records if either username or password don't match. So `if (query.next()) {` will be false.

Comment: You probably should remove `AND password = :password` from the where clause.

Comment: it took me like 2 days. :)

Comment: Now the problem is that it shows when the password does not match only once. then i have to restart the program. or enter a correct login, then again the failed attempt dialog shows

Comment: I now have two query requests `query.prepare(QString("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username"));
 query.prepare(QString("SELECT * FROM users WHERE password = :password"));` but it only displays the failed login attempt the first time and then stops to display anything if i use another incorrect password. if i reenter a wrong username but keep the same wrong password from before it displays "login failed" everytime. what am i doing wrong?

Comment: You don't need to compare the password using a select. Just compare the username and thus if the person entered a valid username the query will return a record. `SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username` Then in your c++ code check to see if the password matches. You actually do that in the shown code. You can also remove the `query.bindValue(":password", password);` part as well.